# Placing of text by specifying distance from axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering, when using the `ax.text` command on two different plots but a plot with which I would like to be the same figure in my paper, e.g.:

```
axScatter_Scatter.text(38.20, 2.76, r'$\mathrm{(a)}$', fontsize=12)
axScatter_Hist.text(2.8, 284.5, r'$\mathrm{(b)}$', fontsize=12)
```

Is it possible, rather than specifying rough xy co-ordinates, to specify a standard distance from the axes? So that both the (a) and (b) label positions are exact?

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated, as I can't seem to find anything in the literature or through other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) of `text` explains you can use the `transform` argument:

```
axScatter_Scatter.text(0.1, 0.1, r'$\mathrm{(a)}$', fontsize=12, 
        transform=axScatter_Scatter.transAxes)
axScatter_Hist.text(0.1, 0.1, r'$\mathrm{(b)}$', fontsize=12, 
        transform=axScatter_Hist.transAxes)
```

Now the coordinates for the text objects are interpreted as fractions of the axes.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, after the below edit it worked perfectly and I have added the edit where the label is in the top left hand corner of the plot which seems to be standard in the astronomical community.

Comment: Many thanks tho for your quick and easy to work with example. Perfect!

Comment: Thanks. I guess I copy/pasted a tad too fast.

Comment: Not to worry, it was just was I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Specific to my code, the above answer by @hitzg worked perfectly but for the following change:

```
axScatter_Scatter.text(0.05, 0.93, r'$\mathrm{(a)}$', fontsize=12, 
        transform=axScatter_Scatter.transAxes)
axScatter_Hist.text(0.05, 0.93, r'$\mathrm{(b)}$', fontsize=12, 
        transform=axScatter_Hist.transAxes)
```

The transform=ax.transAxes was changed to transform=axScatter_Hist.transAxes to be consistent with `axScatter_Scatter = fig.add_subplot(121)`. Which is just my own personal labelling.